# Problema de conexão do Construct 2 com o servidor via AJAX e XML

Tags: php, ajax, xml

Boa noite , sou um iniciante na parte de criação de jogos , e estou tentando aprender a criar a comunicação entre o jogo e o servidor , porem , usando o Construct 2 , estou com problemas , porque parece que o jogo não esta buscando a informação no servidor .

[image: Esta é a parte de Eventsheet do Construct 2]

```
    <?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
echo '<root>';
echo '<Pergunta id="Pergunta"> Quem nasceu primeiro ? </Pergunta>';
echo '<Pergunta id="RespostaA"> O Ovo </Pergunta>';
echo '<Pergunta id="RespostaB"> A Galinha </Pergunta>';
echo '<Pergunta id="RespostaC"> Os Dinossauros </Pergunta>';
echo '<Pergunta id="RespostaD"> A minha Avó  </Pergunta>';
echo '</root>';

?>
```

O código acima , é o código em php , na qual ele deveria buscar no servidor e transmitir no jogo .

Este tipo de jogo estou fazendo atravez de um vídeo do youtube , porém , na vídeo aula dele funcionou , refiz isso umas 3 vezes , e decidi vir pedir ajuda aqui . Peço a ajuda de vocês , pois estou ansioso em concertar esse erro . Grato desde já . O canal é esse : desKompliKa Cursos

Comment: Oi, Bruno, bem vindo ao site. Por favor, coloque o código ao invés da imagem do código, é só **[edit]** a pergunta para modificar isso.

Comment: @brasofilo Desse modo que esta agora ?

Comment: Essa pergunta tem dois anos já, o problema é que o @BrunoLemos não nos deu nenhum detalhe sobre que erro que deu, ou se deu algum erro. Seria mais fácil com o código e não com imagem, mas a interface do Construct2 talvez não ajude nisso. O mais provável é que o problema esteja na formatação do XML, mas posso estar enganado. Precisamos da resposta do Ajax pra ver o que acontece.